# Value Tracing while debugging

Tags: java, debugging

Recently I've had to track down where a specific value in a very large program comes from. Is there a type of tool that allows you to see this easily? Essentially, you would set a breakpoint in a function, and ask the tool to show the 'value trace' for some variable, or a value in that variable.

Debugging this java snippet, and running the tool on the `x` variable at the breakpoint would produce information similar to the following list.

```java
void foo1() {
  int[] array = new int[]{ 5, 6, 7 };

  for(int x : array) {
    foo2(new String[] { Integer.toString(x) });
  }
}

void foo2(String[] x) {
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x)); // breakpoint here
}
```

1. parameter: `String[] x`
2. local function call: `foo2( ... )`
3. array constructor: `new String[] { ... }`
4. library function call: `Integer.toString( ... )`
5. for loop: `for(int x : ...)` from variable: `array`
6. array constructor: `new int[]{ ... }`
7. constant: `5` (pressing continue in the debugger would show `6` then `7`)

Comment: Intellij IDEA allows you to evaluate expressions and print their values when you hit a breakpoint. I imagine most IDEs do.